# react-router-dom v6 Routes showing blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Im routing a page to the root, but its showing up as a blank page, no matter what js file I use. Not sure whats wrong, havent used react since last year but looks like they've updated react-router-dom so it doesnt use Switch anymore. Anyone know the correct syntax so the page shows up? Here are the files:

**WebRoutes.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

// Webpages
import App from './App';
import Welcome from './welcome';
import SignUp from './Signup'

export default function WebRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/'>
       <Welcome />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import WebRoutes from './WebRoutes';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <WebRoutes />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` components don't render routed content as children, they use the `element` prop. Other `Route` components are the only valid children of a `Route` in the case of building nested routes.

```
export default function WebRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Welcome />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Ensure that you have rendered a router around your app.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <WebRoutes />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you. Do you know if theres any documentation for this? Couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: @Roark Nothing other than the official docs, [Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route) and any of the other overviews and guides in the "getting started" section.